# Extending Javascript prototype methods

Tags: javascript

I am having a hard time understanding how this preserves a function an essentially extends it.

I see that `(function(){})` will call a declared function immediately. I don't understand what supplying `open` as a parameter. Finally, I don't understand what goes on with `(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open)`. Is this calling the prototype function?

```
(function(open) {
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
    open.call(this, arguments);
  };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function (open) { .. }` declares a function which takes one argument.
`(..)(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open)` is calling this function and is passing the `open` function of `XMLHttpRequest.prototype` as argument. Yes, it's passing *the actual function* itself; functions can be passed around like values.

So, inside that IIFE (immediately invoked function expression), `open` is the original implementation of `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open`.

Then, inside the IIFE, `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` gets replaced with a new function. Inside that new function, the original `open` function gets called. This by itself isn't too exciting, but it shows how you could wedge in your own code between `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` being called and the actual, original `open` function being executed.

The whole ordeal with the IIFE is just to preserve a handle to the original `open` function which cannot be overwritten by other code under any circumstances, because it's local to a function.

Comment: Thanks. I just am still stuck on `(function (param){})(myParam)`. How can `myParam` be passed to the function? `(function())() ` What is this called?

Comment: It's called an *IIFE*.

Comment: If that makes it easier, rewrite it as `function foo(open) { .. }; foo(XMLHttpRequest...);`. Same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is exact replica of this.

```
//Create a XMLHttpRequest.realOpen function and store the original XMLHttpRequest.open function in it
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.realOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

//Change the XMLHttpRequest.open function
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {

    //Do Your Code Here....

    //Call original XMLHttpRequest.open function which is now saved in XMLHttpRequest.realOpen function
    this.realOpen(method, url, async, user, password);
};
```